# How to know, if running on device or simulator in react native

Tags: ios-simulator, react-native, device, environment

To distinguish between development mode and production mode in react native there is the `__DEV__` constant defined, when Debug = True.

Is there a similar constant defined, that lets me know within the code, if the code is running on the device or in the simulator?

Where else could I get this kind of information from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this [package](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info), then just do :

```
console.log(DeviceInfo.getModel()); // it returns 'Simulator'
```

Answer (score 5):

Since G. Hamaide's answer was posted, the [DeviceInfo package](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) has added the method `isEmulator`.

`DeviceInfo.isEmulator()`

Answer (score 1):

there's a caveat here, `DeviceInfo.isEmulator()` returns a promise, so if you use `if(DeviceInfo.isEmulator())`, it'll return true even if running on a real device.
Use `DeviceInfo.isEmulatorSync()` or `if(await DeviceInfo.isEmulator())`.